# How can I create functions that can be chained together?

Tags: javascript

How can I create a list of functions in JavaScript that preform actions together like this?

I’m sorry I don’t know what it called but something like Jquery when you select something than you add class to it and also you can do something else in the same time!

For Example:

```
list.getAll().count()
```

Or

```
list.getAll().removeLast().dosomthingElse().count()
```

I tried many ways but unfortunately I can’t get it working unless I extend the Function Class which is not what i want!

Comment: You want to know 'how to chain methods in JavaScript.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's called chaining methods. You simply return the object reference (`this`) from the method:

```
List.prototype.getAll = function() {
  // do something
  return this;
}
```

Or if the method produces a new result, you create an object of the same type and return that:

```
List.prototype.removeLast = function() {
  var items = this.items.slice(0, items.length - 1);
  return new List(items);
}
```

(You could also create an object of a different type. For example a `toCollection` method could create a new `Collection` object with all the items from the list and return that.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a method. That's a function attached to an object.

You define it like this:

```
window.myMethod = function(){
    alert(this) ;
}
```

The object doesn't have to be `window`. To chain another method on to the end, use `return this`.

```
window.myMethod = function(){
    alert(this) ;
    return this ;
}

window.myOtherMethod = function(){
    console.log(this) ;
    return this ;
}

window.myMethod().myOtherMethod() ;
```

Now you can use a chain of methods because the second method receives the original object (`window` in this example) from the first.

Comment: Thank you very much much ColBeseder